# How do I properly download and save a list of images?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I have a list of image of URLs and would like to download and save each image. Unfortunately, I keep receiving an Out of Memory exception due to an exhausted heap space. The last attempt saved two images and then threw "Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 33554464 bytes".

My code is shown below. The logic seems correct but I believe the asynchronous calls may be at fault. Is there some adjustment I should make to cause downloading to be sequential? Or is there another method I should be utilizing?

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  // loc is a Set of valid URLs
  // ...

  loc.forEach(retrieveImage)
}

void retrieveImage(String location) {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(location);
  String name = uri.pathSegments.last;

  print("Reading $location");
  http.readBytes(location).then((image) => saveImage(name, image));

} 

void saveImage(String name, var data) {
  new File("${name}")
    ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
  print(name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download them sequentially, you can switch to [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Future#id_forEach). This enumerators through a collection executing a function for each, but waiting for the Future that the function returns to complete before moving on to the next. It, in turn, returns a future that completes once the final iteration has completed.

Instead of

```dart
loc.forEach(retrieveImage);
```

use

```dart
Future.forEach(loc, retrieveImage);
```

and then ensure `retrieveImage` returns the future:

```dart
Future retrieveImage(String location) {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(location);
  String name = uri.pathSegments.last;

  print("Reading $location");
  return http.readBytes(location).then((image) => saveImage(name, image));
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for solving my memory issue. I might like to revisit to support downloading multiple files concurrently. Thanks. I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

If @DannyTuppeny s doesn't solve your problem you can increase the heap size.
I think this should be the flag that does it

```
old_gen_heap_size: 1024 (Max size of old gen heap size in MB,e.g: --old_gen_heap_size=1024 allows up to 1024MB old gen heap)
```

```
dart --old_gen_heap_size=1024 somefile.dart
```

or

```
export DART_VM_OPTIONS="--old_gen_heap_size=1024"
```

http://dartbug.com/13744 also mentions `--new_gen_heap_size` but `dart --print-flags` doesn't list it.
I have no idea if this is supported and what it does.

The problem I see in your code is that all images are started to download almost at once and while they are received they use heap memory. Also @DannyTupeny s code won't change that.

You can either limit the number of files downloaded concurrently by only invoking new requests when previous requests are finished or to use streams to write the data into the file while it is received so it doesn't need to be buffered in memory entirely.
I haven't done this myself yet and will not have time to look into it at least until sunday but maybe someone else can provide more details to such attempts.

To redirect incoming data directly to a file without buffering the entire file in memory this should work but I wasn't able to reproduce the out of memory problem so I can't say for sure.

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:async' as async;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var images = [
    "https://c4.staticflickr.com/4/3880/15283361621_bc72a1fb29_z.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3923/15101476099_6e1087b76c_h.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3899/15288834802_073d2af478_z.jpg",
    "https://c4.staticflickr.com/4/3880/15283361621_bc72a1fb29_z.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5575/15101869429_fa44a80e87_z.jpg",
    "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2941/15100232360_03f3631c44_z.jpg",
    "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2941/15269480156_a28e1c0dbb_b.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3907/15103503127_195ffcd5c0_z.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5595/15265903986_a3210505f4_c.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5567/15100857617_9926f2a189_z.jpg",
    "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2941/15100542247_6e9c3f13ae_z.jpg",
    "https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3852/15099895539_cf43a904a5_z.jpg"
];

main() {
  var futures = <async.Future>[];

  images.forEach((url) {
    futures.add(new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url))
    .send().then((response) {
      var f = new io.File(path.basename(url));
      var sink = f.openWrite();
      sink.addStream(response.stream)
      .then((_) => sink.close());
    }));
  });
  async.Future.wait(futures) // wait for all image downloads to be finished
  .then((_) => print('done'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking into the Streams option myself, but have gotten myself quite confused. I'll try @DannyTuppeny solution and increase the heap size as you suggest. All of the downloads are being done concurrently and this is most likely the issue.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I will try and refactor my code to try your solution out.

Comment: Can't wait to hear your feedback if that solves the memory problem without increasing the heap.