# Allocate more RAM for the Dart VM

Tags: dart

I've created some very memory consuming programs in Dart. They always ran, but now the RAM for the Dart VM is not enough. So, my question is: How can I allocate more RAM for the Dart VM?

I've checked the documentation [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dart-vm/) and also the documentation via `dart --help -v` but couldn't find a possibility to specify an amount of RAM.
Could anyone please tell me how to get more RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set an environment variable to achieve this

> export DART_VM_OPTIONS="--old_gen_heap_size=2048"

but I think you can also pass it as argument

> dart --old_gen_heap_size=2048 -c somefile.dart

see also

- [How to run a dart program with big memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519462)
- [How do I properly download and save a list of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941740)